# XLR Condenser mic to 3.5mm input jack. How do I power the mic?

Tags: microphone, conversion, xlr, power, phantom

I am using a zoom h1n audio recorder, which takes a 3.5mm (1/8) input jack. I want to upgrade my microphone setup to a large-diaphragm condenser microphone. All the condenser microphones I am checking out require phantom power. Is there a power supply available that will do:

```
3.5 input jack (1/8) <---> Convert to XLR <---> add phantom power <---> Condenser Microphone.
```

I can't seem to find anything that provides this. I really don't want to replace my recorder, I would rather just power and convert the XLR mic separately.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a DI box. They typically use a 9v battery to provide phantom power. You connect the XLR from mic to the female XLR port on the DI and then you can use the link 1/4" jack socket with a step-down (6.35 - 3.5mm) adapter to your Zoom recorder.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I am looking for. I will continue my research based on this.

Comment: This will not work. Phantom power most often is 48V

Answer (score 0):

There are phantom power adapters available. Some run on batteriet. One example from the lot is "Art Phantom II Pro". I might recommend searching on a studio supplier web site, one example might be thomann.de  Search for "Phantom Power Supply".
Another example might be this "Saramonic SmartRig+". Or "iRig PRE".